# IBM Watson visual recognition - invalid API key

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'm trying to use the visual recognition from IBM Watson using their API.
Here is the POST request I am sending:
`https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={MY_API_KEY}&version=2016-05-20` and I specify my image in the body parameter.

I always get:

```
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "statusInfo": "invalid-api-key"
}
```

I got my key from Bluemix 3 hours ago (they said the key should be working in 5 minutes).

Any ideas? Thanks

**EDIT**

Since this morning, I have another error:

```
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "statusInfo": "invalid-api-key-permissions"
}
```

Is this me or Watson is still under maintenance?

Answer (score 4):

The Visual Recognition service was experiencing problems recognizing keys; the development team has resolved the problem as of July 14. (There is additional discussion of this issue on the [IBM developerWorks Answers forum](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/282775/visual-recognition-no-longer-accepting-keys/), and you can open a support ticket on a specific key issue at [Bluemix support](https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/)).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I hope this problem will be resolved soon, I need the Visual Recognition for a proof of concept.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. I never tried this service, so I am unsure whether this is a problem from my side or IBM's. Can we be notified when the service runs smoothly again?

Comment: I will post to this thread when the service is running smoothly again.