# Watson visual recognition: error 401

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'm trying npm module watson-developer-cloud for visual recognition.
I'm getting `{ error: 'invalid-api-key', code: 401 }`
 when trying to run following code:

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var fs = require('fs');

var visualRecognition = watson.visual_recognition({
 version: 'v3',
api_key: process.env.API_KEY || 'e2493f2bacdbea8becedcc7aafecdfb4133XXXXX',
 version_date: '2015-05-19'
 });

 var params = {
   images_file: fs.createReadStream('./resources/gopher.png')
 };

 visualRecognition.classify(params, function(err, res) {
  if (err)
 console.log(err);
 else
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927516/ibm-watson-visual-recognition-invalid-api-key

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem raised in [IBM Watson visual recognition - invalid API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927516/ibm-watson-visual-recognition-invalid-api-key). The Visual Recognition service was experiencing problems recognizing keys; the development team has resolved the issues as of July 14. (There is additional discussion of this issue on the [IBM developerWorks Answers forum](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/282775/visual-recognition-no-longer-accepting-keys.html), and for issues with specific keys, you can [open a Bluemix support ticket](https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/).