# IBM Watson: Invalid API Key

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, ibm-watson

I'm trying to make requests on the Visual Recognition API and getting the response error below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2016 13:53:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 67
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

{
    "status": "ERROR",
    "statusInfo": "invalid-api-key"
}
```

I've already tried to recreate my account and the Visual Recognition Service many times this week, and the **API Key** provided by Bluemix is always invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same problem raised in [IBM Watson visual recognition - invalid API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927516/ibm-watson-visual-recognition-invalid-api-key) and [Watson Visual Recognition - error 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062000/watson-visual-recognition-error-401). The Visual Recognition service is currently experiencing problems recognizing keys; the development team is working to resolve the problem. There is additional discussion of this issue on the [IBM developerWorks Answers forum](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/282775/visual-recognition-no-longer-accepting-keys.html). For issues with specific keys, you can [open a Bluemix support ticket](https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/).